# code for json to html

Tags: json, html-parsing

I have following json format. I want to display each field in html. How can i retrieve the values from json to html

> [{"node_title":"king","nid":"6","Body":"
>
> This is king
>
> \n"},{"node_title":"sree","nid":"3","Body":"
>
> ggbderfrtgrsf
>
> \n"}]

Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>JSON Object Creation in JavaScript</h2>

<p>
Name: <span id="jname"></span><br />
Age: <span id="jage"></span><br />
Address: <span id="jstreet"></span><br />
Phone: <span id="jphone"></span><br />
</p>

<script>
var JSONObject= {
"name":"John Johnson",
"street":"Oslo West 555",
"age":33,
"phone":"555 1234567"};
document.getElementById("jname").innerHTML=JSONObject.name
document.getElementById("jage").innerHTML=JSONObject.age
document.getElementById("jstreet").innerHTML=JSONObject.street
document.getElementById("jphone").innerHTML=JSONObject.phone
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Use some thing like this. this is from [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_intro.asp)

Comment: thanks.. can u please tell me wat in case of having json object arrays. can u please tell me the syntac of $.each loop for that

Comment: @SreekanthChandrabhatla you could just use a for loop like this 

for(var i = 0; i < JSONArray.length; i++) {  // read JSON here }

Answer (score 0):

Using [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/)

```
<div>
   <!-- ko foreach: values -->
    <p>node_title: <span data-bind='text: node_title' ></span></p> 
    <p>nid: <span data-bind='text: nid'></span></p> 
    <p>Body: <span data-bind='text: Body'></span></p>
    <!-- /ko -->    
</div>​
```

javascript

```
var ViewModel = function(data) {
    this.values = ko.observableArray(data);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel([{"node_title":"king","nid":"6","Body":"This is king\n"},{"node_title":"sree","nid":"3","Body":"ggbderfrtgrsf\n"}]));​
```

[JSFiddleExample](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/5241/)

Comment: Thanks llya. Adding point to my problem. Am using rest webservice from drupal that returns the above json format. I need to consume it in my android moble(phonegap). Am looking for any javascript azax call to use that servce.

Comment: @SreekanthChandrabhatla response from server you can save using `this.values(response)` in you view model. To sent request you can use `jQuery.ajax`